# Loop in a script until file exists

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to have a script find a file in /tmp called sleep.txt but instead it keeps looping

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
until [ $(ls -la | grep -w "sleep.txt" | wc -l) != 0 ];
do
        echo "Sleep.txt doesn't exist as of yet..."
done
        echo "Sleep.txt now exists!!!"
        sleep 2
exit
```

Comment: If you are on linux, it would be much better to monitor file creation with [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

Comment: @John1024 Can it be used in a bash script easily?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, it is quite easy to script.  I added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 9):

This script does not use polling.  In other words, it does not do periodic checks.  Instead, it uses a tool, [`inotifywait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html), that is designed to monitor changes to the filesystem.

In this script, `inotifywait` monitors the current directory (`.`).  Every time that a file is created in that directory, `inotifywait` emits its name and the script checks to see if it matches `sleep.txt`.  If so, it announces the creation:

```
[ -e sleep.txt ] || while IFS= read -r fname
do_
    [ "$fname" = sleep.txt ] && break
done < <(inotifywait -m -q -e create -e moved_to --format %f .)

echo "Finally, sleep.txt now exists!!!"
```

#### More details

The options used for `inotifywait` have the following meanings:

- `-m` means keep monitoring the directory.  In other words, don't stop the first time something happens worth reporting.
- `-q` means be more quiet than normal.
- `-e create -e moved_to`  means only report on file created or moved into this directory.
- `--format %f` tells it to print the filename every time a file creation event occurs
- `.` tells it what directory to monitor.  A period, `.`, always means the current directory.

#### Installing `inotifywait`

On Debian-like systems, `inotifywait` is part of the `inotify-tools` package and can be installed via:

```
apt-get install inotify-tools
```

For installation instructions for other linux distributions, see the [wiki for inotify-tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki#getting).  If you want the source code, see the [inotify-tools package on github.](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools)

#### MS Windows and OSX

`inotifywait` is available for Linux systems and also runs under Cygwin.

To read about similar tools for Windows, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows).

For information on similar tools for Mac OSX, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac).

Comment: Great answer! Did you mean to add more text? The last sentence is incomplete.

Comment: @Edward Thanks.  I just removed that stray word.

Comment: +1 Apparently it needs the package `inotify-tools`, at least on Linux Mint, though inotify is part of the kernel. And inotifywait seems to keep running a while after the script exits, at least a minute or so until creating another file in the directory... tested with pgrep in another terminal.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, it is the same on debian: `apt-get install inotify-tools`.

Comment: Excellent, the true solution to _x_, and not an improved _y_ like my answer (already +1'd this morning)! Three comments: (i.) `<(...)` IMHO does not work with sh. (ii.) The script loops infinitely if sleep.txt already exists. (iii.) Do you know on which platforms this will work? Linux and (as I observed right now) Cygwin... anything else? Would be a nice info for future visitors.

Comment: @mpy Thanks! (i) Yes, process substitution is not POSIX.  It will work under bash (this question is tagged bash) as well as zsh and ksh{88,93}.  If you don't use process substitution, then you want to use a pipeline and, in a case like this, that has its own issues. (ii)  Yes, if `sleep.txt` already exists, this will wait for it to be deleted and created again.  If that is a problem, I should add a test before the loop.  (iii) I had thought inotifywait was limited to Linux.  I am pleased to hear that it works on Cygwin also.  (I expect that other OSs have similar features.)

Answer (score 7):

Parsing `ls` [is not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead, you can use the `-e` test to check if a file exists:

```
#!/bin/sh

until [ -e sleep.txt ]; do
    echo "sleep.txt doesn't exist as of yet..."
    sleep 1
done

echo "sleep.txt now exists!!!"
sleep 2
```

Consult `man test` for more informations about `test` command.

Comment: Just a small comment: `[[` is Bash-specific, so you may either want to change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`, or replace the double brackets with single brackets `[` and `]`. (Also, the indentation is slightly confusing.)

Comment: The Q is tagged "bash", though confusingly the OP is using `/bin/sh`...

Comment: @Edward: I improved my answer according to your points. However I'm not sure about `[[ ... ]]`. It seems to work in `sh`, too, but might depend how _ancient_ sh is `;)`

Comment: "It seems to work in `sh`, too" – There are many implementations of `sh`. The [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html) is what you can expect to be supported by any sane implementation. `[[` is not there, [`[` is there](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). Any `sh` *may* support more features, but the good practice while publishing code for `sh` is not to go beyond the specification. This is how you write *portable* shell code. In answers here I often find portability a virtue.